# Increment Javascript object values by "adding" an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript object:

```
{"Vanilla": 36, "Chocolate": 50, "Stracciatella": 24, "Coffee": 18}
```

to which I would like to "add" this array:

```
["Vanilla", "Amarena", "Chocolate", "Pistachio"]
```

The result I want is this:

```
{
    "Vanilla": 37,
    "Chocolate": 51,
    "Stracciatella": 24,
    "Coffee": 18,
    "Amarena": 1,
    "Pistachio": 1
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
var me = ["Vanilla", "Amarena", "Chocolate", "Pistachio"]
var all = {
    "Vanilla": 36,
    "Chocolate": 50,
    "Stracciatella": 24,
    "Coffee": 18
}
var keys = Object.keys(all);
for (var i = 0; i < me.length; i++) {
    if (me[i] in keys) {
        console.log("keys:" + keys + " - " + me[i] + " in keys");
    } else {
        console.log("keys:" + keys + " - " + me[i] + " not in keys");

    };
}

console.log(keys);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works

the first part of the code in **your** fiddle

```
var me = ["Vanilla", "Amarena", "Chocolate", "Pistachio"]
var all = {
    "Vanilla": 36,
    "Chocolate": 50,
    "Stracciatella": 24,
    "Coffee": 18
}
```

Now the answer:

```
me.forEach(function(key) { // forEach iterates through an array 
    all[key] = (all[key] || 0) + 1; // create new item if it doesn't exist
});
```

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once per array element.

For a more detailed description of .forEach see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) where the above description came from

as this question was tagged `jQuery`, lets add some `jQuery` code, just for laughs

```
$.each(me, function(unusedIndex, key) {
    all[key] = (all[key] || 0) + 1;exist
});
```

> **jQuery.each()** A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties. - source http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Here's me playing with myself - http://jsfiddle.net/7ephp3f4/1/

Comment: although this answer is more elegant it does not take into account the coding level the OP obviously has. therefore the answer from @anthony-blackshaw is better suited as answer for this specific post.

Comment: @hurrtz So make this level higher. Array methods are as primitive knowledge as simple loops. Both are not quantum mechanics. So this answer makes as much sense as the the with for-loop.

Comment: @JaromandaX Care you elaborate what `.forEach` is and how it works?

Comment: Fine answer anyway, omitting comments. Use `all[key]++` to kill one byte more.

Comment: I agree. Apart from the commenting this is a very nice approach. Thanks for going into detail about the mechanics. +1

Comment: @hurrtz, you are right to suggest that I might not be totally ready for the || operator, but it only took a few minutes for me to learn enough about it to understand this answer!

Answer (score 3):

The following code allows you to increment the values within your object `stock` based on the keys in your array `stockUpdate`:

```
var stockUpdate = ["Vanilla", "Amarena", "Chocolate", "Pistachio"];
var stock = {
    "Vanilla": 36,
    "Chocolate": 50,
    "Stracciatella": 24,
    "Coffee": 18
};

for (var i=0; i < stockUpdate.length; i++) {
    var stockType = stockUpdate[i];
    if (stock[stockType] === undefined) {
        stock[stockType] = 0;
    }
    stock[stockType]++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there,

```
var me = ["Vanilla", "Amarena", "Chocolate", "Pistachio"]
var all = {
    "Vanilla": 36,
    "Chocolate": 50,
    "Stracciatella": 24,
    "Coffee": 18
}
var keys = Object.keys(all);
for (var i = 0; i < me.length; i++) {
    if (keys.indexOf(me[i]) >= 0) {
        console.log("keys:" + keys + " - " + me[i] + " in keys \n");
        all[me[i]]++;
    } else {
        console.log("keys:" + keys + " - " + me[i] + " not in keys \n");
        all[me[i]] = 1;
    };
}

console.log(all);
```

you can also use reduce to "merge" the `newItems` into `items`

```
var items = {"Vanilla": 36, "Chocolate": 50, "Stracciatella": 24, "Coffee": 18}
var newItems = ["Vanilla", "Amarena", "Chocolate", "Pistachio"];

var result = newItems.reduce(function(pre, curr) {
        // use double == to check when the item is either undefined or null
        pre[curr] = (pre[curr] == null? 0 : pre[curr]) + 1;
        return pre;
// pass items as the initial data to reduce
}, items);

console.log(result);
```

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

in this case, I reduce the `newItems` list, from left to right, calcuate the count in the `items` object, and return the calculated items.

Comment: In the end, I kept experimenting and used reduce. +1 for the encouragement!

Answer (score 0):

It is a good moment to use http://underscorejs.org:

```
var me = ["Vanilla", "Amarena", "Chocolate", "Pistachio"];

var all = {
  "Vanilla": 36,
  "Chocolate": 50,
  "Stracciatella": 24,
  "Coffee": 18
};

_.each(me, function(name) {
  if (_.has(all, name)) {
    all[name]++;
  } else {
    all[name] = 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: Still counting bytes? Underscore is powerful common inventory to manipulate arrays and objects, it may be useful in other cases of the project.